# How to correctly retrieve view from fragment in main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

is there a specific way or a specific moment in which I can retrieve in my MainActivity a view from a Fragment, being sure that the element is already initialized?

I of course used the `findViewById()` method in my MainActivity but it returns null if the Fragment is not already initialized, so I've tried to call an initializing method of MainActivity with a broadcast in `onStart()` fragment method, when the application starts it works but when there is a rotation of the screen the initializing method returns null and the application crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this in your oncreateView()

```
View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentA, container, false);
```

and than after you Can get your view like this

```
textView  = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

now you are able to use this view.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, now I've put all the code that changes the fragments views in the fragment itself and I've implemented the interfaces for the correct communication between the Activity and the Fragment so I can modify the content view without worrying when retrieve the fragment variables. For these last I've initializated them in the onCreateView() method from the inflater and it works fine.